# Passing value to the hidden field from java-script not working

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, hidden-field

This is the hidden field and the javascript.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdn" runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("hdn").value = "helo";
</script>
```

And i tried to access the hidden field value in the .cs file as `string st = hdn.value`.
But it shows null when i check the value using linebreaker

Comment: When you check the value (i meain `st = hdn.value`? On page load? If is, it is after post back or not? How do you check value `using linebreaker`? What's more, the ID of element is invalid. The `ID` property tells us about server control id, but client id is different (id in input field, auto-generated).

Comment: try document.getElementById('<%= hdn.ClientID %>').value = "helo";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ClientID` instead of server id and also make sure that *javascript* is executed after the `hdn` field being added to *DOM*, you can put the `script` tag just before the closing *body* tag.

```
document.getElementById("<%= hdn.ClientID %>").value = "helo";
```

If you have .net framework 4 and above you can also set [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx) to `static` to keep the server id on client unchanged.

*HTML*

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdn" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" />
```

*Javacript*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("hdn").value = "helo";
</script>
```